# Internal Server Error when using PHP CURL

Tags: php, curl, cookies

Note: I know this question is sort of "too specific", but please help, I don't know where to turn.

This is a somewhat very difficult question to answer, but I don't know where to turn to...Any help would be so greatly appreciated.

I am trying to use PHP curl to get the html from a site that requires you to log in, uses cookies, and uses csrf tokens. Overall, I am able to login with their login page and get the cookies from their login page, but when I try accessing certain pages within their website, I get a following error from their service. Other pages though work fine.

"We're sorry! Something has happened, and we're unable to complete your request at this time. Waiting a few minutes and trying again will often fix the problem."

ALONG WITH:

```
Time: 7/22/2016, 10:52:36 AM
Reference id: undefined
Url: undefined
Browser: undefined
undefined
```

Very generic and with no helpful information, so I really don't know what to do - or even if it's a problem with my code or their server or both. When I try logging in normally from my browser, I am able to access the page. Could you please help finding how to solve this problem?

A lot of further information for reference: The page I am trying to extract html from is https://www.edline.net/UserDocList.page. On a normal log in procedure, when I have logged in, if I type this into the URL bar, it redirects to https:// www. edline. net / UserDocList.page?vsur="" where "" is a string of seemingly arbitrary characters unique to the user found no where else on the site. Additionally the following is a copy of the request headers sent when I try accessing the page normally:

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:BIGipServerprod_pool=2009639104.20480.0000; route=route.01; JSESSIONID=53ACA25565D22D9154B3A751A2099FA2; ENSID=d027dfe4-c595-4f82-aabf-6ee2831c50fc; LLG=false; XT=1469199593977; pgt=c1469199601532t
DNT:1
Host:www.edline.net
Referer:https://www.edline.net/UserDocList.page
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36
```

There is the "query string parameter" that they added: vusr:ae4776f9b4fa1bf53745a49013852ec4.

Additionally, an analysis of their fully-loaded correct page, https://www.edline.net/UserDocList.page?vusr=ae4776f9b4fa1bf53745a49013852ec4 reveals that there is the following form:

```
<form name="EventForm" method="post" action="/post/UserDocList.page" style="display: none;">
 <input type="hidden" name="invokeEvent" value="" />
 <input type="hidden" name="eventParms" value="" />
 <input type="hidden" name="sessionRenewalEnabled" value="yes" />
 <input type="hidden" name="sessionRenewalIntervalSeconds" value="300" />
 <input type="hidden" name="sessionRenewalMaxNumberOfRenewals" value="25" />
 <input type="hidden" name="sessionIgnoreInitialActivitySeconds" value="90" />
 <input type="hidden" name="sessionHardTimeoutSeconds" value="1200" />
 <input type="hidden" name="ajaxRequestKeySuffix" value="0" />
 <input type="hidden" name="csrfToken" value="pImuc5n1fmYtvDHlZ9BCXf3geewbtwVNP8GwM9keFOGKCjDZto75BUsPuhwZk53WC07zcotxK40ez780gs2SwD2Y5Mt8mVGwYjWPACr0XkniVd1djN2Ug30Ith8UVAEl" />
```

Additionally, here are the cookies that I have on file (refreshing generated every time after the user logs in to MY site):

```
www.edline.net  FALSE   /   FALSE   0   ENSID   c3fd35f6-3366-47f9-b64c-179a5d715f1b
www.edline.net  FALSE   /   FALSE   0   BIGipServerprod_pool    2160634048.20480.0000
www.edline.net  FALSE   /   FALSE   0   route   route.00
www.edline.net  FALSE   /   FALSE   0   JSESSIONID  DF6CE0BD455B27011868E03C33B39CA3
www.edline.net  FALSE   /   FALSE   0   pgt c1469199156590t
www.edline.net  FALSE   /   FALSE   0   LLG false
www.edline.net  FALSE   /   FALSE   0   XT  1469199156537
```

AND the code being used to try to access the page:

```
//$temp_csrf_token = $file->find('input[name=csrfToken]');
//$csrf_token = $temp_csrf_token[0]->value;

curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.edline.net/UserDocList.page');
//curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
//curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('invokeEvent'=>'', 'eventParms'=>'', 'sessionRenewalEnabled'=>'yes', 'sessionRenewalIntervalSeconds'=>'300', 'sessionRenewalMaxNumberOfRenewals'=>'25', 'sessionIgnoreInitialActivitySeconds'=>'90', 'sessionHardTimeoutSeconds'=>'1200', 'ajaxRequestKeySuffix'=>'0', 'csrfToken'=>$csrf_token)));
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
//curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "BIGipServerprod_pool=2177411264.20480.0000; route=route.01; JSESSIONID=81A1CD15160AB9B64F5274C90526CD67; ENSID=ebd459f7-8d44-4987-aded-f3be65714f7f; LLG=false; XT=1469140120196; pgt=c1469140126591t");
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, realpath($temporary_cookie_file));
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, realpath($temporary_cookie_file));
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$results = curl_exec($session);

print($results);
die();
```

As you can see from commented out code, I have tried several things that I thought might fix the problem:
(1) manually getting cookies from the file and sending them through CURLOPT_COOKIE, if maybe the CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR/FILE was the problem.***
(2) getting the CSRF token from the page generated upon logging in and passing it into the "form" of "post/UserDocList.page" along with other values of the form.
(3) mimicking a "regular" browser's headers, thinking they have some sort of bot detection system.

***I know, in the code, it seems like I did this manually hard-coded, but I also tried it by reading the newly generated cookie file.

None of this has worked. I don't know where the problem is or what to do now. Other pages of the website work fine, but it is noteworthy that those pages don't "redirect" like this one and contain less user-specific data.

If you need more info: You can log in to this website www.edline.net/Index.page with my credentials, if requested. PLEASE, any help would be greatly appreciated. Getting this page's HTML is crucial to the function of my website.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you *always* get those errors on the same pages with curl?  And how do you get to those pages?  Are they form posts or simple URL's you are issuing GET requests to?

Comment: @drew010 (1) yes, (2) well, I am posting form data to www.edline.net/post/InterstitialLogin.page which is the log in page and then passing the cookies sent back from the login in a cURL call to www.edline.net/UserDocList.page. Also, if you need/want to access the edline site, you can use the credentials -> screenname: faustozurita and password: Parkland